# drop postgresql schema public without losing extensions

Tags: postgresql, permissions

As part of my development workflow, I often use

```sql
drop schema public cascade;
create schema public;
```

in order to get a clean state of the test database before re-loading my table and stored procedure definitions.

With the right setup, these statements work without superuser permissions.

My table definitions depend on extensions such as

```sql
create extension "pgcrypto";
create extension "uuid-ossp";
```

and whenever I drop the schema, they are lost...
which wouldn't be a problem, if they didn't require super-user permissions to re-create.

Possible solutions I have considered:

#### Make my user super-user

```
alter user myuser with superuser;
```

Sadly, this is the number-one suggestion when you google for any sort of permission-related issue. I would very much like to avoid super-user permissions, even on my development and testing system.

#### Manually re-create the extensions every time I drop the schema

To my best knowledge (and experimental results), the problem here is that I have to re-connect to the database as regular and super-user several times...

- connect as regular user to run `drop schema` / `create schema`
- connect as superuser to run `create extension`
- connect as regular user to run the various `create table` / `create function` statements

This is a lot of hassle and I'd rather avoid it.
It'd be acceptable to switch once, but twice is definitely too much. When I run `create schema` as superuser, the regular user cannot create tables anymore.

#### Revoke permission to drop the extensions

```sql
update pg_extension set extowner=0;
```

... that's what I tried, but it didn't seem to change anything.

### ?

Is there an other, creative solution for this issue? Maybe

- dropping all individual parts of the schema but not the schema itself
- granting permissions to re-create extensions to my user
- creating the extensions in a different schema, if such a thing is possible?
- something else entirely?

My searches there didn't yield anything useful, but that may be due to my limited experience in the topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I question your desire to routinely drop the `public` schema, but it should be no problem if you do it like this:

- create a new schema `extension` and put it on the `search_path`
- use `CREATE EXTENSION ... SCHEMA extension` to create the extension objects in that schema

I personally use the `public` schema for extensions and put my data in a different schema.